# Hovering one item to display the child in another div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I ran into a problem and couldn't find an easy solution.
I have a couple of tags which have an img assigned to them and I would like that their respective image is displayed in another div, when I hover over it or click the tag.
At the moment the images will be shown, but at the location of the hover tag.

Jquery or Js is also an option :)

**EDIT**
As of now the IMG is shown in the left box and I want to be displayed inside the right box on hover. Preferable would be if it would also work with onClick so it stays when I move my mouse away.

There are multiple images (about 100 different ones)

I will provide some code below

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}

figref:hover img {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
}

figref img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld a
    <figref idref="f0001">
      FIG. 1A <!--ATM When I hover this the Image is displayed below-->
      <img class="normal" src="./images/imgf0001.png">
    </figref>
    <figref idref="f0002">
      FIG. 2A 
      <img class="normal" src="./images/imgf0002.png">
    </figref>
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld a
  </div>
  <div class="right"> <!--Here is where the image should be displayed when I hover the figureref-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where do you want the image displayed?

Comment: I wrote it in the CSS as a comment. The Img should be displayed in the right box not inside the left box, where it is located.

Comment: Make a script that is triggered by the `onmouseover` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oen way can be to :

1. search for the img inside the figRef element
2. copy the img in the innerHTML of right panel

```js
document.querySelectorAll('figref').forEach(function(fig) {
fig.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
  var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
  document.querySelector('.right').innerHTML = target.querySelector('img').outerHTML;
});
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}

figref img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld a
    <figref idref="f0001">
      FIG. 1A <!--ATM When I hover this the Image is displayed below-->
      <img class="normal" src="./images/imgf0001.png">
    </figref>
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld   
   <figref idref="f0002">
      FIG. 2A <!--ATM When I hover this the Image is displayed below-->
      <img class="normal" src="./images/imgf0002.png">
    </figref>a
  </div>
  <div class="right"> <!--Here is where the image should be displayed when I hover the figureref-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this seems to only work with one image. How would I go about, if I have about 100 images and I only want the one that is currently hovered to be displayed?

Comment: you can use querySelectorAll to target all image inside a page

Comment: i edit my sample in consequence

Comment: Thanks again this is exactly what I needed. I will have to look into JS more :) Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the image under the `.right` div, the image and the figref are no longer siblings and hence it is not a CSS thing to control the visibility.
If the structure is a must, you would need to use javascript. Check the snippet below:

```js
document.querySelector('figref').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  document.querySelector('.right > img').style.display = 'block'
})

document.querySelector('figref').addEventListener('mouseleave', function(){
  document.querySelector('.right > img').style.display = 'none'
})
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}
.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}
.right > img {
  display: none;
}
figref:hover {
  color: red;
}
figref:hover + .right > img {
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk  kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld a 
    <figref idref="f0001">
        FIG. 1A
    </figref>
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk  kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld a 
  </div>
  <div class="right"> 
    <img class="normal" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1646864052090-071a579e1346?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=687&q=80">
  </div>
</div>
```

.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, but I cannot change the location of the img. The side will be generated automatically and I cannot rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

This can also easily be done with JS as you probably know. To do this with css, you want to make sure the element you want displayed above the parent has the following css:

```
position: absolute; //ensures position is relative to nearest positioned ancestor
z-index: 2; 
width: 36px;
height: 36px;
```

Full answer with updated css:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}

figref:hover img {
  visibility: visible;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  z-index: 2;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px black;

}

figref img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld a
    <figref idref="f0001">
      FIG. 1A <!--ATM When I hover this the Image is displayed below-->
      <img class="normal" src="./images/imgf0001.png">
    </figref>
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld a
  </div>
  <div class="right"> <!--Here is where the image should be displayed when I hover the figureref-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just add `top:0;` and `left:50%;` on `figref:hover img` and will work as requested

Answer (score 0):

This can be done manipulating the DOM with Javascript. It would be easier if the image —or a positioning image— is set inside the div where you want it to appear.

The solution can't be done as it is with CSS only, and the Javascript solution depends on your preferences: ¿do you want to use Jquery or do you need to do something more complex?

Comment: JQuery would indeed be awesome

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 500px;
}

figref img {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 max-width:400px;
 border:8px solid #fff;
 border-radius:6px;
}
figref:hover img {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 2px 4px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 1s; 
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {opacity:0;box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
  40% {opacity:1;box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}  
  100% {opacity:1;box-shadow: 2px 4px 35px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
}

figref{
  font-weight:800;
}
figref:hover {
  color:#52f;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld a
    <figref idref="f0001">
      FIG. 1A <!--ATM When I hover this the Image is displayed below-->
      <img class="normal" src="https://api.heinsoe.com/v3/portfolio/storage/20200101/zmt.jpg">
    </figref>
    lorem ipsum delum loresd a sadk kdkas l ldpalo ea ld apsld a
  </div>
  <div class="right"> <!--Here is where the image should be displayed when I hover the figureref-->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I was using this before, but I really needed it to be shown inside another div not just in the position :) Have good day